How do I fix this Azure Pipelines failure: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 [Full error message included]
Up until last Wednesday my pipelines ran fine. There have been no package upgrades or .csproj file updates so it's been hard for me to pin down the reason for the pipeline issue. The error is as follows:
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error : clang++ exited with code 1: [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error : Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :   "_nw_path_monitor_create", referenced from: [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :       -[MLKITx_MDDNetworkUtilities init] in MLKitMDD [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :   "_nw_path_monitor_set_queue", referenced from: [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :       -[MLKITx_MDDNetworkUtilities init] in MLKitMDD [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :   "_nw_path_monitor_set_update_handler", referenced from: [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :       -[MLKITx_MDDNetworkUtilities init] in MLKitMDD [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :   "_nw_path_monitor_start", referenced from: [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :       -[MLKITx_MDDNetworkUtilities init] in MLKitMDD [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :   "_nw_path_uses_interface_type", referenced from: [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error :       ___34-[MLKITx_MDDNetworkUtilities init]_block_invoke in MLKitMDD [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error : ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]
    /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_17.5/17.5.8018/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1641,3): error : clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) [/Users/runner/work/1/s/MyTestApp/MyTestApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios]

My pipeline details are as follows:

XCode version : 15.4
VM image      : macOS-14
.NET version  : 8.x (8.0.303 used for the pipelines in question)

I have tried building the project with a physical mac with the same details and OS version number and my app builds fine. If anyone know what is happening your help is much appreciated because this is causing me a lot of trouble.
.CSPROJ File Sample (Stripped down)
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-ios;net8.0-android</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>My.TestApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>My Test App Contractor App Dev</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.testapp</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>9e4f6176-37b7-4abf-9f9e-779336fb439d</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <Configurations>Debug;Release;Test;Dev</Configurations>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-ios'">
        <BundleResource Include="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="MetroLog.Maui" Version="2.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="5.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="5.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="8.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly" Version="8.0.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps" Version="8.0.21" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase" Version="2.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="7.5.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Fragment.Ktx" Version="1.6.2.1" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net8.0-android'" />
        <PackageReference Include="CardsView.Maui" Version="0.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Prism.Maui.Rx" Version="9.0.271-pre" />
        <PackageReference Include="Prism.DryIoc.Maui" Version="9.0.271-pre" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
        <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <BundleResource Include="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\My.TestApp.Business\My.TestApp.Business.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Dev|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
        <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
        <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
        <AndroidEnableProfiledAot>False</AndroidEnableProfiledAot>
        <RunAOTCompilation>False</RunAOTCompilation>
        <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
        <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
        <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
        <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
        <AndroidEnableMultiDex>True</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
        <EnableLLVM>False</EnableLLVM>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
        <CodesignProvision>202406_Development_Distribution</CodesignProvision>
        <CodesignKey>Apple Distribution: TestApp Limited </CodesignKey>
        <MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Dev|net8.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
        <MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>
        <UseInterpreter>true</UseInterpreter>
        <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
        <ProvisioningType>manual</ProvisioningType>
        <CodesignKey>Apple Distribution: TestApp Limited </CodesignKey>
        <CodesignProvision>202406_Development_Distribution</CodesignProvision>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- DO NOT REMOVE Fix for "ITMS-90482: Invalid Executable - The executable 'My.TestApp.app' contains bitcode." -->
    <!-- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10989 -->
    <!-- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12863 -->
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Properties used to strip bitcode from frameworks when using Visual Studio for Mac -->
        <_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets Condition="'$(OS)'=='Unix'">_ExpandNativeReferences</_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets>
        <_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets Condition="'$(OS)'=='Unix'">_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksOnMac</_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets>

        <!-- Properties used to strip bitcode from frameworks when using Visual Studio for Windows -->
        <_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets Condition="'$(OS)'!='Unix'">_ComputeFrameworkFilesToPublish</_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets>
        <_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets Condition="'$(OS)'!='Unix'">_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksOnWindows</_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterTarget" Condition="'$(_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets)'!='' AND @(_FrameworkNativeReference-&gt;Count()) != 0" AfterTargets="$(_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets)" DependsOnTargets="$(_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets)" />

    <Target Name="_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksOnMac" Condition="('$(OutputType)'!='Library' OR '$(IsAppExtension)'=='True') AND '$(_SdkIsSimulator)'=='False'">

        <!-- Find the bitcode_strip command -->
        <Exec Command="xcrun -find bitcode_strip" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
            <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="_BitcodeStripCommand" />
        </Exec>

        <!-- Strip the bitcode from frameworks -->
        <Exec Command="$(_BitcodeStripCommand) %(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity) -r -o %(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity)" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksOnWindows" Condition="('$(OutputType)'!='Library' OR '$(IsAppExtension)'=='True') AND '$(_SdkIsSimulator)'=='False' AND '$(IsMacEnabled)'=='true'">

        <!-- Strip the bitcode from frameworks -->
        <Exec SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" Command="&quot;%24(xcrun -find bitcode_strip)&quot; %(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity) -r -o %(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity)" />

        <CopyFileFromBuildServer SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" File="%(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity)" TargetFile="%(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity)" />
    </Target>
</Project>

Azure Pipeline YAML snippet (Variables)
variables:
    # VSVERSION: 17.10.5
    dotNetVersion: 8.x
    projectPath: My.TestApp/My.TestApp.csproj
    businessProjectPath: My.TestApp.Business/My.TestApp.Business.csproj
    buildParameters: /p:ApplicationId=$(applicationId) /p:ApplicationDisplayVersion=$(VersionName) /p:ApplicationVersion=$(Build.BuildId) /p:ApplicationTitle=$(applicationTitle)

Azure Pipeline YAML snippet (Steps)
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Set .NET Version
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '$(dotNetVersion)'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Install MAUI
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet nuget locals all --clear 
      dotnet workload install maui --ignore-failed-sources
      dotnet workload list

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    selectOrConfig: config
    projects: $(projectPath)
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.Config
    
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Set XCode Version
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        xCodeVersion=15.4
        echo "Setting XCode version to $xCodeVersion"
        sudo xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode_$xCodeVersion.app"
        echo "XCode version successfully set to $xCodeVersion"

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Build iOS App
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet publish $(projectPath) -f net8.0-ios -c $(buildConfiguration) /p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64 /p:FirebaseCrashlyticsUploadSymbolsEnabled=true $(buildParameters)

Thanks in advance.

Can you share more details about the Pipeline definition and the .csproj file smaple? This will be helpful to investigate the issue.

On the other hand, have you successfully built locally using xcode 15.4 and  Microsoft.iOS.Sdk 17.5.8018 pacakge?

@KevinLu-MSFT I have added my .csproj sample, please let me know what other pipeline definitions I should add aside what I put.

Are you using Azure Pipelines? If yes, you can share the pipeline definitions details.  In this case, we can see the details of the build and the task where the issue occurred.

@KevinLu-MSFT I can successfully build with xCode 15.4 and iOS SDK 17.5. Can you please be a bit specific about the pipeline definition or tell me how? Sorry I am not 100% sure what you mean. Do you want the entire yaml file? I'm not sure what exact information you are asking for, apologies.

Yes. You can share the entire yaml file content. If the content is large, you can share the affected task definition (partial yaml code).

@KevinLu-MSFT I've added it alongside the variables it uses, hope this helps and thank you!

@KevinLu-MSFT I really appreciate your help, I have gone ahead and added additional pre-build steps so you have more visibility over the pipeline

Can you try to use self hosted agent to run the pipeline and check the result?

@KevinLu-MSFT I just rerun it now with the azure pipeline and it worked fine?!... I haven't made any changes to the pipeline aside add -v diag to the dotnet publish command to get very detailed logs. I am happy and unhappy at the same time because if this happens again it seems I have no direct way to fix the problem.

if you are using Microsoft hosted agent, can you check the image versions of the agent between failed and success build?  E.g. 20240811 or 20240804

@KevinLu-MSFT I just checked them and they are both the exact same - 20240804.1

Since the image version is not changed, the software settings should be same between pipelines.  It indeed hard to determine the root cause of the issue.  But I suggest that you can configure a self-hosted agent based on your Macos machine as a Backup. If you encounter this issue again, you can switch to use self-hosted agent to let the pipeline work. It will reduce the interruption time of your Pipeline
